# Safari High Avg Energy Impact

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, safari

Under the Energy Monitor, it always shows high Average Energy Impact (1000+) for Safari. Is this normal? I have attached the screenshots. Although I formatted the entire disk and reinstalled the OS, the problem has not been fixed. What is the reason for this issue, and is it possible to fix it?

No plugin/extension is installed. It happens even if Safari is only displaying Google.

My environment:

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)
- Processor: 3.1 GHz Intel Core i7
- Memory: 16 GB 1867 MHz DDR3
- Safari 8.0.7

Thank you!

[image: Energy]
[image: CPU Usage]

Comment: What about CPU usage?

Comment: CPU usage is not high. I added the screenshot to the question.

Comment: This is likely an issue that only a trained and certified Apple Technician can work out. The Diagnostics generate MBs of data and you need to know where exactly to look to sort out the issue. It is possible that you picked up Malware. Sophos and Avast are freeware AV packages from respected firms though there are some questions surrounding Avast's privacy policy. This if a rundown of Mac AV http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2406379,00.asp Run a scan and see if anything turns up.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing top proccesses by CPU % and CPU time?

Comment: Thank you, AMR. McAfee is running on my computer, but it has not detected anything. Although I have used several anti-virus softwares, they did not pick up malware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd simply ignore it. Energy Impact is just an arbitrary number showing how much energy an app is consuming (each instant and on average).

Activity Monitor is simply telling you that the app which uses the most energy is Safari.

To make sure that Safari is not eating up on CPU, you can check the CPU usage over time, for example using a tool like 'uptime' from the command line (simply launch the Terminal an type uptime), this will tell you the uptime of the system and the load average over the past 1, 5 and 15 minutes, this number should be close to (or less than) 1 on Yosemite. A load average constantly above 2 (or more) could indicate some process sucking up on CPU, which can found using Activity Monitor.